# Поучить данные из ячейки при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить данные из ячейки таблицы с классом one при клике по кнопке.Данные нужо получить из того же ряда где находится кнопка.

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td class = "one">Текст 1</td>
        <td><button class="button">Получить текст 1</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one">Текст 2</td>
        <td><button class="button">Получить текст 2</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: для примера хотбы в параграф

Comment: @ЮрийТкачук: где этот параграф?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('button')].forEach(e => {
  e.onclick = (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Текст 1</td>
    <td><button class="button">Получить текст 1</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Текст 2</td>
    <td><button class="button">Получить текст 2</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Либо если у кнопки несколько соседей:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('button')].forEach(e => {
  e.onclick = (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.one').innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Текст 1</td>
    <td class="two">Ненужный текст</td>
    <td><button class="button">Получить текст 1</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="two">Ненужный текст</td>
    <td class="one">Текст 2</td>
    <td><button class="button">Получить текст 2</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное помогло !!!

Comment: Пожалуйста.....